# InvalidPipeArgument for DatePipe, IST timezone not supported by default

Tags: angular, datetime, angular-pipe, date-pipe, angular-date-format

I have tried using DatePipe to format date values which I get from REST API. The format of the date string in REST API is like this: *Wed Mar 28 12:20:11 IST 2018*.

It works fine when the timezone in the string is UTC, EST etc. However it is resulting in below error if the timezone string is IST, CET or some other.

```
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Wed Mar 28 12:20:11 IST 2018' for pipe 'DatePipe'
at invalidPipeArgumentError (VM616 common.umd.js:4313)
at DatePipe.transform (VM616 common.umd.js:4495)
at MyPipe.transform (VM1283 my.pipe.ts!transpiled:20)
```

A sample reproducer is available here: https://plnkr.co/edit/UPNJG9ejpYdkYQivq3cj?p=preview. I tried creating a DatePipe instance as below, but it did not work.

```
new DatePipe('en-IN')
```

Could someone please tell me how to add support for timezones which are not supported by default in DatePipe.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the [documentation for DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) in more detail, I stumbled upon this..

> `timezone` to be used for formatting. It understands UTC/GMT and the continental US time zone abbreviations, but for general use, use a time zone offset, for example, `'+0430'` (4 hours, 30 minutes east of the Greenwich meridian) If not specified, the local system timezone of the end-user's browser will be used.

Sending a format with `GMT+530` or just `+530` instead of `IST` worked fine.
Finally I ended up modifying my format like *Wed Mar 28 12:20:11 GMT+530 2018*

Comment: One thing that I observed, the format like `+480` it will be 4 hours and 80 minutes, it will not treat at a minute value like the `moment().utcOffset(480)`, in that case, will be 8 hours.